# Problems with an alignment

Tags: align

How to solve this alignment?

[image]

I wrote `\[a^2+...\]` but I couldn't align it in my document. What's the best way to center a long equation like this one?

I use LaTeX

Comment: What, precisely, are you trying to align? Which alignment point should be used? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I would like to center this equation, but it's so long. What's the best way to solve this problem? write two times this symbol \\[\]\ and divide the equation in two?

Comment: Are you really trying to typeset `a^2+b^2+...`? If not, please provide a more realistic example, i.e., the actual equation you're looking to typeset.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2\\ 
e ^2 + f^2 + g^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to split it automatically? I mean If the equation is so long I don't know if I split in two , three or four parts.

Comment: I'm not so sure :(   I always did this way

Comment: @user26832 I think the idea is that something like a displayed equation should *not* be split automatically because it needs to be split where it 'makes sense' i.e. according to the meaning. And TeX can't do that because all it knows about is boxes.

Comment: Could you complete the code? `split` is not a standard LaTeX environment, after all. Your answer could be improved if it provided a compilable example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options that you can choose from. You can either use `\multiline` or `\split` depending on how you would like to align. I would suggest to use `\split` in your case. And it will be like the following with the alignment point at `$+$`.

```
$\begin{split}
a^2 & +b^2 + \ldots \\
    & +l^2 + \ldots 
\end{split}$
```

Comment: I couldn't do it: "Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here \end{split}"

Comment: You need to put `\split` in another math environment like `\equation` or `\align` because it is a subsidiary math environment which can not exist independently.